# Why does the C++ function template code not compile?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have searched the web, but I could not find the answer to my problem> Why does the C++ template code not compile? Once I remove the last line before the return statement, it compiles and runs as expected.

I use g++ version 4.3.4. I will greatly appreciate the expert help.

Regards,
maicah

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

void mult(int* ptr)
{
 std::cout << "void mult(" << *ptr  << "): line: " << __LINE__  << ", function: "<<    __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void multIndirect(T* x)
{
    std::cout << "void mult(" << *x  << "): line: " << __LINE__  << ", function: "<< __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void apply(void (*funcPtr)(int*), int* pVal)
{
    std::cout << "apply(" << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>((uintptr_t) funcPtr)  << ", "  << *pVal << "): line:"  << __LINE__  << ", function: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    funcPtr(pVal);
}

template <typename Func, typename T>
void applyIndirect(Func funcPtr, T* x)
{
  std::cout << "apply(" << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>((uintptr_t) funcPtr)  << ", "  << *x << "): line:"  << __LINE__  << ", function: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  funcPtr(x);
}


int main(void) {

int y = 300;

mult(&y);
apply(mult, &y);
apply(multIndirect, &y);
    applyIndirect(multIndirect, &y);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**I get the compiler error:**

```
CPPTemplate.cpp: In function int main():
CPPTemplate.cpp:47: error: no matching function for call to applyIndirect(<unresolved         overloaded function type>, int*)
make: *** [CPPTemplate.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect the compiler to deduce the actual value of template parameter `Func` for `applyIndirect` and, consequently, template parameter `T` for `multIndirect` from this call

```
applyIndirect(multIndirect, &y);
```

?

In this call `multIndirect`'s `T` could be `double` or `char` or `SomeOtherType` or anything else. You made your `Func` parameter a completely *free* type and you provided the compiler with absolutely no means to figure out what type it is supposed to be. This is what causes the error.

Given your declaration of `applyIndirect`, to make it compile you have to explicitly tell the compiler the value of `T` in `multIndirect`

```
applyIndirect(multIndirect<int>, &y);
```

Now knowing the type of `multIndirect<int>` the compiler will be able to figure out what `Func` is supposed to be. Or, alternatively, you can explicitly tell the compiler the value of `Func` in `applyIndirect`

```
applyIndirect<void (int *)>(multIndirect, &y);
```

Knowing the value of `Func` the compiler will be able to figure out what `T` for `multIndirect` is supposed to be.

However, looking at the body of your `applyIndirect` it looks like you want to use `funcPtr` with parameter `x` of type `T *`. That means that type of `funcPtr` is not really supposed to be a free type. It is supposed to actually depend on `T`. Why did you make it a free type then? Why did you introduce that extra template parameter `Func`? What was the purpose of that?

Instead of introducing an extra template parameter, you should have simply declared your `applyIndirect` as

```
template <typename T>
void applyIndirect(void funcPtr(T *), T *x)
{
  funcPtr(x);
}
```

That would be immediately consistent with how `apply` is declared.

Now the compiler will understand the link between the type of `x` and the required type of `funcPtr`. With such declaration you will be able to call

```
applyIndirect(multIndirect, &y);
```

The compiler will figure out from the type of `&y` that `T` is `int`. This, in turn, will mean that the type of `funcPtr` is `void (int *)`. And that will make it instantiate `multIndirect` for `T == int`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify *which* `multIndirect<T>` you want to apply indirect:

```
applyIndirect(multIndirect<int>, &y);
```

You don't need to specify the type if you use `apply`, because the compiler infers the correct type:

```
void apply(void (*funcPtr)(int*), int* pVal);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It worked, but why do I not need to do the same in: apply(multIndirect, &y);

Comment: Either `applyIndirect(multIndirect<int>, &y)` or `applyIndirect<void (int *)>(multIndirect, &y)`. Both will achieve the same effect. But the OP presented no real reason to make the function type a free, non-deducible template parameter. A better approach would be the one I described in my answer: get rid of `Func` parameter entirely and declare the function pointer type in terms of `T`.

Comment: This suggestion works. I tried to use the same idea in my next question about a function template that accepts a template template parameter Stack, but it not compile for me. @AndreyT

Comment: This answer is very helpful. Do you mind commenting on my other question: "Why does this function that takes template template parameter not compile?"  @AndreyT